# problemas no insert em asp classico (replace)

Tags: sql-server, asp, replace, vbscript

Gente, no meu banco de dados, a coluna está configurada como `numeric (18,2)`

daí eu tenho um campo em um formulário que a pessoa digita o valor e ele vai para minha tabela.

o `insert` está assim:

```
entrada = Replace(Request.form("entrada"),",",".")
```

só que se a pessoa digitar o valor com ponto E vírgula, por exemplo `"100.328,74"` ele dá o seguinte erro:

> "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Não é possível
>   converter um valor char em money. A sintaxe do valor char está
>   incorreta."

se ela digita só o ponto: `"100.328"` o valor vira `100,33` (exibicação no site com o `formatnumber`"

se a pessoa digita só a vírgula:
`"100,32"` o valor vai certinho pro banco de dados `"100.32"` e aparece `"100,32"` no site, de acordo com o `formatnumber`

alguma ideia?

não tenho como doutrinar todo mundo que for inserir o valor a não usar o ponto que separa o milhar/milhão

gostaria de programar pra já ir o valor certinho.

obrigada!

Comment: O valor sempre terá centavos?

Comment: Sam, não é sempre, mas pode ocorrer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código irá sempre retornar o valor no formato aceito pelo banco de dados. Por exemplo:

`100.328,74` será `100328.74`

`100,32` ou `100.32` será `100.32`

`100,3` será `100.3`

Em resumo, se houver centavos o código separa os centavos do valor principal e junta os dois novamente separados por um ponto, que é o formato aceito para valores monetários. Caso não haja centavos, o valor continua o mesmo, apenas retirando-se os pontos que separam os milhar:

`100.328` será `100328`

**Código:**

```
entrada = Request.form("entrada")

Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "[.,]\d{1,2}$"
Set RegExRes = regEx.Execute(entrada)
Set regEx = Nothing

If RegExRes.Count > 0 Then

   centavos = RegExRes(0)
   centslen = len(centavos)
   centavos = replace(replace(centavos, ",", ""), ".", "")
   valor = replace(left(entrada, len(entrada)-centslen), ".", "")

   entrada = valor&"."&centavos

Else

   entrada = replace(entrada, ".", "")

End If
```

Comment: não deu certo... se a pessoa digitar 100.00 por exemplo, ele vira 1,00

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora amigo.

Comment: muito obrigada, deu certo!

Answer (score -1):

Neste caso basta você primeiro remover os pontos, e depois trocar as virgulas por ponto. Ex:

```
entrada = Replace(Replace(Request.form("entrada"),".",""),",",".")
```

Comment: isso, quando a pessoa digita o ponto, ele multiplica o valor